# Objective-C - How do I search an NSArray of MKDirectionResponse(s) for a direction response with a specific source and destination?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm at wits end. It seems I can never get it to work...

I'm using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: to select and manipulate the items I want in the array. Any other way to do this?

Comment: You need to show your code and state why it doesn't work for people to be able to help. Unless you want the short answer "Yes, there is more than one way to search/iterate over an array" – but I expect you won't find that too helpful!

Comment: It works but I don't like how it looks. Tried looking into NSPredicate but it seems even uglier.

Comment: Well "beauty (and hence ugliness) is in the eye of the beholder" - but none but you have beheld your code, so how can others even attempt to suggest something less ugly/more beautiful?